# Postgresql Update Values in a Column by Passing Arguments to A Function

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, subquery

I have a Postgresql Server 11 running in Windows environment. I am trying to update all values in a column of a table based on return data from call to another function. Here is my progress so far:

```
UPDATE joa_clinics SET clinic_long = subquery.longitude
    FROM (SELECT longitude FROM  geocode_clinics_and_sales('NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', '123 XYZ Street, Chicago IL 99999' ) ) as subquery; 

UPDATE joa_clinics SET clinic_long = subquery.longitude
    FROM (SELECT longitude FROM  geocode_clinics_and_sales('NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', select from joa_clinics.ServiceAddress::text ) ) as subquery;
```

So the table `joa_clinics` has a `clinic_long` column which needs to be updated based on the return from the `geocode_clinics_and_sales` function call; that function returns `longitude` and `latitude` values. And so far my top query works if I pass a hard-coded address. But the address should be the values of `ServiceAddress` from the `joa_clinics` table, as shown in the bottom query. But in that query I get a syntax error around the second `select`. To help: there is a `record_id` unique column in the `joa_clinics` table.

Maybe I am on wrong path? Maybe do in a loop? I am running these queries inside pgAdmin but that should not matter. For now, I can just manually run them--one and done!

**UPDATE**

I think I am getting closer but all the values are the same and I need a WHERE clause in this updated query:

```
do
$$
declare
    f record;
begin
    for f in SELECT ServiceAddress FROM joa_clinics
    loop   
    raise notice '%', f.ServiceAddress;
    UPDATE joa_clinics SET clinic_long = subquery.longitude FROM
    (SELECT longitude FROM  geocode_clinics_and_sales('NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', f.ServiceAddress )) as subquery; 
    
    end loop;
end;
$$
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. I think I had tried some variation of the function in the question but get 'more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression' error

Comment: You could make the second query 'work' by enclosing it in `()`. The error then would be that you are returning multiple values. To make this work would require some sort of loop to work with an individual address at a time.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out right after I posted my original comment.

Comment: Yes, I think I am now looking into using a Cursor; didn't want to but got to move on. Thanks.

Comment: I will see if I can figure out using a Cursor per: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-cursor/ Thanks

Comment: I think I am getting closer and updated the Question with an updated query just now??

Comment: Not tested and assumes information about `joa_clinics`: `(SELECT longitude FROM  geocode_clinics_and_sales('NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', f.ServiceAddress ) WHERE joa_clinics.serviceadress = f.ServiceAddress)`.

Comment: Thank you. I think I already have a solution as posted as Answer. Also, there can be duplicate serviceaddress value in the data; I think, as I had indicated in the Question, record_id is the unique field. What I have as my Answer is inefficient but it works. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up doing. In a loop. Didn't want to but got stock long enough and had to move on. May make it part of some db 'trigger' later on.

```
do
$$
declare
    f record;
begin
    for f in SELECT record_id, ServiceAddress FROM joa_clinics
    loop   
    raise notice '%', f.ServiceAddress;
    UPDATE joa_clinics SET clinic_long = subquery.longitude FROM
    (SELECT longitude FROM  geocode_clinics_and_sales('NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', f.ServiceAddress )) as subquery where joa_clinics.record_id = f.record_id; 
    
    end loop;
end;
$$
```